# Send commands to screen within screen

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

1. login to Server1 and run screen
2. SSH to Server2 and connect to an existing screen session
3. Realise ^A commands are procesed by Server1's screen only

Is it possible to control Server2's screen in this situation? Even if only to detatch from it.

The only thing I could see to do was tell Server1's screen to kill its window containing the SSH session.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  One of the commands you can send Screen with its metacharacter (`^A`) is a literal `^A`, which is done with the `^A-a` (ctrl-A, lowercase a) sequence.  On the help screen (`^A-?`), you will see one key defined as `meta`.

So, in short, to send a command to a screen within a screen (e. g. to disconnect the nested screen), you would press `^A-a-d`, which would send `^A-d` to the nested screen, detaching it and leaving the first-layer screen connected.